# dropdown menu doesn't always show up in corporateclean

Tags: routes, theming, navigation

I customized a theme from corporateclean and now, adding a drop down menu, the drop down doesn't show up on the rest of the page. The link is http://athleticedgefitness.com/contact where it shows the Links drop down; if you go to any other page, you see that the drop down doesn't show up. Why not? How can I fix this?

I am using Drupal 7.

Clearing the cache didn't do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, where the problem is. In the parent menu you also have to select "show as expanded" option to display the child menu in drop down or whatever configuration you have.

[image]

Steps (if you may need):

1. Goto Structure->Menus
2. Select the Menu and click list links
3. Find the parent menu and edit it
4. Inside that you will have option to choose "show as expanded", Check that
5. Clear the cache and you are good to go.

Comment: Most welcome :)